# SQL, matching all the values in column b and return column a for those matches

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-match-all, relational-division

I'm only looking at one table, I have the values I need to match, so.

```
Col A / Col B
1 / 1
1 / 2
1 / 3
2 / 2
2 / 3
4 / 1
4 / 3
```

So the values I pass in would be 1 and 3 and I'd want to return 1 and 4.

I've tried a group by with a could, where I've had to use two sub queries, but it didn't work.

EDIT: Ideally I'd like to use a select query as I need to use this query within another query which I'm building up outside of sql server.

EDIT2: Ideally I'd like to pass in my input as a csv string

Comment: I don't get it. Why 1 and 3 return 1 and 4?

Comment: what is your criteria for input and output. please provide more explanation.

Comment: the criteria for input would be `where col_B IN (1,3)` and output would be `select Col_A`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select ColA 
from your_table
where ColB in(1, 3)
group by ColA
having count(ColA) > 1
```

Comment: Why do you have the `HAVING` statement in there :/

Comment: @StuartBlackler: Because without it, it would return all ColA's that have **either** `1` or `3`  as value. But the OP needs ColA's with **both**

Comment: Its because of the requirement to show the values in ColA that satisfy BOTH ColB `where` clauses. Having said that i dont think this will work when there is more than two input criteria

Comment: Your `HAVING` clause should be `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ColB) = @Criteria`, Where @Criteria is the number of different requirements for colB.

Comment: @GarethD: Not if ColA and ColB form a composite key, or their uniqueness is ensured through some other method.

Comment: @weenoid A composite key, or unique constraint would only remove the need for the `DISTINCT` key word. The OP has stated that they "could be passing in numerous input values", so if there were 3 values passed `HAVING COUNT(ColA) > 1` would not work, it would have to be `HAVING COUNT(ColA) > 2` which is why I have suggested the change.

Comment: @GarethD: Ah, gotcha. That's kind of implied, I would hope the OP has enough common sense to figure it out ;).

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly the values passed in relate to ColumnB and the return values come from ColumnA:

```
SELECT      A.ColumnA
FROM        [YOUR TABLE] A
INNER JOIN  [YOUR TABLE] ON ( A.ColumnA = B.ColumnA AND B.ColumnB = 1 )
WHERE       A.ColumnB = 3
```

Comment: Thanks, however, I could be passing in numerous input values :(

Comment: How are you passing the values in? Could you provide some code?